# UIWebView doesn't show the last tweets anymore

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview, widget

I display tweets in the UIWebView using method loadHTMLString where in the html  I use twitter widget.
The code has worked well until yesterday. Now in stead of last tweets the white screen is shown.

```
html=@"<script charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js\"></script>    <script>    new TWTR.Widget({    version: 2,    type: 'profile',    rpp: 4,    interval: 30000,    width: 250,    height: 300,    theme: {    shell: {    background: '#333333',    color: '#ffffff'    },    tweets: {    background: '#000000',    color: '#ffffff',    links: '#4aed05'    }    },    features: {    scrollbar: false,    loop: false,    live: false,    behavior: 'all'    }    }).render().setUser('chetassofa').start();    </script>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL: nil];
[self.webView setDelegate:self];
```

P.S. the widget displays the tweets if I insert it into online html editor. http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

html code:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('user').start();
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should format your html code to make it readable.

Comment: I edited the question, but i think the problem is not in the html. I suspect that they(twitter dev) changed something.

Comment: add this in features of javacscript:  hashtags: true,

timestamp: true,

avatars: false,